# Is it more efficient to convert an exception's stack trace into byte[] array or ByteBuffer (Java)?

Tags: java, arrays, stack-trace, bytebuffer, printstacktrace

I need to log the exception into the database. The database API states I can either pass the value as ByteBuffer or as byte[] array. So which is more efficient?

```
private final static byte[] getThrowableStackTraceBytes(Throwable throwable) {
    StringWriter throwableStackTraceStringWriter = new StringWriter();
    throwable.printStackTrace(new PrintWriter(throwableStackTraceStringWriter));
    return throwableStackTraceStringWriter.toString().getBytes();
}
```

vs.

```
private final static ByteBuffer getThrowableStackTraceByteBuffer(Throwable throwable) {
    ByteArrayOutputStream throwableStackTraceByteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    throwable.printStackTrace(new PrintStream(throwableStackTraceByteArrayOutputStream));
    ByteBuffer throwableByteBuffer = ByteBuffer.wrap(throwableStackTraceByteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray());
    return throwableByteBuffer;
}
```

I think the overall operation will be more efficient if I were to use ByteBuffer, especially when it is handled after it is being passed into the database method. Am I right?

(Specifically, I need to log the exception into Hypertable, and it uses the Thrift Java API.)

Comment: Have you tried benchmarking the difference? Is this a significant bottleneck in your application?

Comment: Why are you trying to use bytes? Wouldn't a stack trace be more naturally stored as a string? Also, why is efficiency a concern? If you are getting enough exceptions for efficiency to be an issue you have bigger problems. Solve those instead.

Comment: No bottleneck or efficiency problems yet. I'm just beginning to write the server-app. It is just a good habit to properly log all exceptions.

Comment: Well, I just examined the database API. Passing either byte[] array or ByteBuffer will be the same, as the former will be wrapped into a ByteBuffer anyway.

Comment: I agree that performance and logging exceptions are both important. But the performance of logging exceptions may be much less important than other aspects of that logging code. Your effort in the logging may be better spent on things like capturing the right information, making it reliable, making non-exceptional logging fast, etc.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The most efficient option is like to be a combination of the two.

```
private final static byte[] getThrowableStackTraceBytes(Throwable throwable) {
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    throwable.printStackTrace(new PrintStream(baos));
    return baos.toByteArray();
}
```

though I suspect writing it to the database will be many times more expensive.

Comment: The return method "return baos.toByteArray();" - returns byte[] - does not work because the return type is ByteBuffer.